# How is StringBuilder more efficient than normal "+"?

Tags: java, string

Can you explain to me why using StringBuilder works much faster than just adding strings with "+" every time? For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    stringBuilder.append(arr[i]);
}
str = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Is much faster than:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    str = str + arr[i];
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: That's not a duplicate...

Comment: `toString()` rather than `ToString()` makes me think this is java, not C#. In any case, please correct your tags for the language you are describing. `StringBuilder` is a class, and may have different implementations, rendering some answers potentially invalid.

Comment: If this is a Java String question, my understanding was that String concatenation is "faster" with the + operator because the JDK/JVM optimises for the most efficient approach, the last time I looked it was suggested that it would use StringBuilder under the hood.  It was suggested that unless you are concatenating in a loop you should use the +.  Admittedly this was back in JDK 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is more efficient than string concatenation because string concatenation creates a new immutable string each time you use it, while the string builder creates a [single buffer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a34c9647-4313-4c10-950e-cea569535179/string-concatenation?forum=netfxbcl) for appending characters to.  [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2839d5h5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the C# doc states that the String object is immutable and the StringBuilder object is dynamic.  It also states

> When you modify the StringBuilder, it does not reallocate size for itself until the capacity is reached. When this occurs, the new space is allocated automatically and the capacity is doubled. You can specify the capacity of the StringBuilder class using one of the overloaded constructors.

However, according to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14936/StringBuilder-vs-String-Fast-String-Operations-wit), `string.Join()` has the best algorithm for appending characters to a string.

According to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) in the Java documentation, `String`s are immutable, while `StringBuilder`s are essentially the same, but can be changed.

It appears that using string concatenation results in the overhead of creating a new immutable string, while using a string builder just results in characters being appended to a buffer.  Creating and initializing a new object is more expensive than appending a character to an buffer, so that is why string builder is faster, as a general rule, than string concatenation.